# Why is there a black shadow on my baked image?

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects, baking

not sure how to explain this so apologies if this doesn't make complete sense, but I am having the hardest time with my baked image. For some odd reason, there is some black shadow circle on a part of my baked image that I have no idea why it is there? In the view, there is no shadowing like that so I don't know why it shows up when it's baked. There is also some weird light strip too, which again is not shown in the original.

[image]

[image]

If someone knows how to get rid of these issues I would be so appreciative because I'm ready to give up in frustration.

Comment: Probably can be matched to the occlusion that comes from where the parts are close together between the upright leg and the arching piece where it would be bolted together or welded.

Comment: Hi! I'm very new to blender so I apologize for my ignorance but I kind of understand ambient occlusion, kind of not also, but how would I try to fix this? Do I need to change certain things with ambient occlusion? Thank you for your helpful comment!

Comment: The place where the two objects touch, that prevents rays from touching the surface so the image comes back as dark or black. If you were to bake them not touching at all with more distance and then move them back after the bake, then you'd get the UV mapped texture without the black areas.

Comment: @CraigDJones Hi! Apologies for this super late response but I appreciate your help! I figured it out after looking at your comment and other one here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a result of the ambient occlusion image. If this doesn't show up in the final render then it probably isn't an issue.

Comment: Hi! I'm actually converting this to a game (The Sims 4) so I need the baked image to be as clear as possible. I'm also having difficulty with the baking of the legs because they also look quite blurry? So, these two problems are making me go mad trying to learn how to fix them.

Comment: If the Sims gives you the option to add reflection (metallic/glossy) shading in game, it is probably better to remove all reflection when you bake in blender.

Comment: My point was that if you can't see the black spot when the image is wrapped on to the mesh, then it shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: @EdwardHurley Hello! So sorry for this very late response but yes, the sims does have that already build into it however the objects end up looking, well, not very dimensional and I wanted mine to at least look a bit more realistic. The baked image is what the program will assign to it so the baking is very important to get right. Thank you for your comment as it helped me figure this out!